# How can ISRO's RISAT satellites search for the lost IAF AN-32?

Tags: artificial-satellite, isro, earth-observation, radar

The Indian Air Force has [lost contact with AN-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Indian_Air_Force_An-32_disappearance) (transport aircraft)  on a mission. ISRO is going to deploy [RISAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RISAT) to search for the missing [plane](http://www.thehindu.com/news/national/search-for-an32-aircraftdifficult-moment-for-us-says-iaf-chief/article8898175.ece?homepage=true) as the search area has widened. How will such satellites  help? Are the new navy P8I Posiedon sub-hunter planes not fit to do such a task?

Comment: Questions get better attention if the title makes clear what the asker wants to know, and it makes it easier for others to find the information later, so i edited it to fit that standard style. Also i added a link to the Wikipedia article on the news story, as with time news links can break, while Wikipedia articles improve.

Answer (score 2):

RISAT-1 and RISAT-2 both carry [synthetic aperture radar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_aperture_radar) systems which can create detailed maps of the surface below.  There has been talk of using these systems to identify wreckage on the ground for quite a while now, but in the late 1990s, when a lot of these ideas were being proposed, the resolution was simply too low to make it a reliable option.  [NASA actually did some research in this area](http://searchandrescue.gsfc.nasa.gov/techdevelopment/sar2.html) too, but that's been indefinitely on hold for quite some time.

Here's a sample paper from the late 90s

http://wmsmir.cits.rncan.gc.ca/index.html/pub/geott/ess_pubs/219/219846/13148.pdf

Abstract: (emphasis mine)

> This  paper  summarizes  some  results  of  studies  at  the  Canada  Centre  for  Remote  Sensing  (CCRS)  using  Synthetic  Aperture  Radar  (SAR)  imagery  from  spaceborne  systems  for  the  detection  of  crashed  aircraft.      Studies  have  been  carried  out  using  detected  products  (intensity  values  only)  and  interferometric  methods   (using   complex   imagery).      **Due   to   the   low   resolution   of   single   polarization single frequency spaceborne SAR imagery  (approximately 8 metres ground range being the best currently available from operational remote sensing satellites),  it  is  seen  that  such  imagery  cannot  currently  be  used  with  much  optimism  although  the  techniques  themselves  show  promise.**  Further  study  is  needed  to  examine  if  the  better  resolutions  that  will  be  available  from  future  systems  such  as  RADARSAT-2  make  possible  the  reliable  detection  of  crashed aircraft.   Other research, not described in this manuscript, is 
>   underway at CCRS through  the  support  of  the  National  Search  and  Rescue  Secretariat  examining the  contributions  to  Search  and  Rescue  that  can  be  made  using spaceborne polarimetric SAR systems including RADARSAT-2.

According to [this article](http://www.thehindu.com/sci-tech/technology/article3350204.ece), RISAT-1 has a resolution that can be varied between 50m and 3m, and also has a "spotlight mode" where this resolution can be as good as 1m.  This is definitely in the range where it could be useful if we have a general idea of where to look.

Realistically, I'm not sure how much good the satellites will do, especially compared with the aircraft and submarines already deployed, but it is an idea that works in theory, so you can't really fault them for going for it.